# Using GDAL on IIS Web APIt

Tags: c#, iis, gdal

How do you setup gdal libraries to be recognized in IIS? Has any done this? I'm always getting cannot load dll or depencies, even though ive alreeady copied all gdal dlls on the bin folder.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is it working locally with Visual Studio? Can you add the link where you downloaded GDAL libraries from.

Comment: http://gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1700-x64-gdal-2-1-2-mapserver-7-0-2.zip

Comment: http://gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1700-x64-gdal-2-1-2-mapserver-7-0-2.zip     i downloaded the compiled libraries and headers. I created a managed c++ dll that uses gdal headers, if i use the dll on a windows apps on the win 2012 server it runs ok, but if i use the dll on web api and run in IIS 8.5 win server 2012, it always says cannot load dependecies , did fusion log and it shows all the dependency of the gdal failed loading. So it seems that there is a different approach to load external dlls on IIS 8.5.